# How to import data into Realm

Tags: swift, xcode6, realm

I would like to import data into Realm. Actually Realm browser can add objects, but it will take much time. Does anyone have idea about that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to add the objects in code.

Comment: Yup, probably that is the best way to add the objects. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, using JSONImport is much better.
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably just to write a bare-bones app that does the importing, using the normal Realm API.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd suggest as well. Run it in the simulator and it would be pretty easy to extract the Realm file from there and add it to the bundle for your real app.